# Rails twitter gem set up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, rubygems

I've installed the twitter gem :https://github.com/sferik/twitter to my site, I've added an application to my twitter account and I've put the following code in an initializer:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
  config.consumer_secret = YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
  config.oauth_token = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN
  config.oauth_token_secret = YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
end
```

now on my view I have:

```
- Twitter.user_timeline('username')
```

Comment: Updated my answer based on your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have experience with the twitter gem. But usually you would put something like this in an initializer.

So i would put it in `myproject/config/initializers/twitter.rb`

**Update**

Try

```
= Twitter.user_timeline('username')
```

Note the `=` instead of the `-`

Comment: I've tried that, but it throws an error unless i put quotes around the actual tokens. And when I do, the tweets don't render

Comment: That probably has to do with something other than the initializer. I suggest that you post a new question, since it is outside the scope of this question. There you can include some more of your relevant code.